# Show different Lessons inside different Modules in Learning Management System using Django

Tags: python, django

The Project is about LMS. Students are able to learn from courses uploaded by instructors assigned by the Super admin.

I want to get all lessons related to one Module. for example Module A should have lesson a and lesson b while Module B should have lesson c and lesson d respectively.

Module A and B are Modules inside a Course created by Super Admin. Lesson a, b, c and d are added by instructors via the Django admin dashboard.

***myapp/Models.py***

```py
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Module(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, ...)

class Lesson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, ...)
```

***myapp/views.py***

```py
def module(request, pk):
    template = 'myapp/module.html'

    module = get_object_or_404(Module, id=pk)
    lessons = module.lesson_set.all()

    context = {'lessons': lessons}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

***myapp/urls.py***

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('lesson/<int:pk>/', views.lesson, name="lesson"),
]
```

***myapp/module.html***

Used `module.id` in the HTML to achieve a dynamic HTML accordion using a for loop, that is, the name of the module appears as a button, when clicked a drop down shows the list of lessons inside this accordion

```html
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
  {% for module in modules %}
      <div class="accordion-item">
         <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-heading-{{module.id}}">
             <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#flush-collapse-{{module.id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-                                      
                controls="flush-collapse-{{module.id}}">
                   {{module.name}}
              </button>
         </h2>

         <div id="flush-collapse-{{module.id}}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-
           labelledby="flush-heading-{{module.id}}" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
             <div class="accordion-body">
                <ol type="1">
                    {% for lesson in lessons %}
                        <li><a href="{% url 'lesson' lesson.pk %}">{{lesson.name}}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ol> 
             </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Below is the Original accordion html templates

```html
<div class="accordion-item">
   <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
     <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-
       toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-
       expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
        **Name of the Module Goes Here**
     </button>
     </h2>
     <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-
     labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
       <div class="accordion-body">
         <ol type="1"> 
            <li><a href="#">**name of the lesson goes here**</a></li>
         </ol>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

***My actual Results***

Same Lesson is repeated in Different Modules

***What i want***

Different lessons should show up in different modules. One Module should show all lessons related to the module

***Screenshot of my Module***

***Module 1 showing lesson head***

[image]

***Module 2 showing lesson head***

[image]

From the above screenshots, lesson (head) is reapeated in both Module 1 and 2

Comment: this line `lessons = lesson.module_set.all()` should be `lessons = module.lesson_set.all()` right ?

Comment: yes, you are right. making changes now

Comment: Still question is confusing. In url I can see module/moduleID, but in html you are showing multiple modules and corresponding lessons. In HTML what you want actually is showing all modules and correspoding lessions OR one module with its lessons ?

Comment: @itzMEonTV  Not really, i double checked it. The code runs okay when adding lessons in a single module hence am able to view a list of lessons inside one module.But  when you add more than one Module and add lesson to this new module, the module one lessons are still visible in module two

Comment: In the HTML am using an accordion to display the name of the Module, when clicked a drop down shows a list of lessons inside this Module, i used the `module.id` to achieve a dynamic accordion so that when another module is added it comes with another accordion

Comment: Since you `module` object is already present as a context, may be you can rewrite this line `{% for lesson in lessons %}` to `{% for lesson in module.lesson_set.all %}` in the template itself

Comment: @itzMEonTV congrats, its working

Comment: @itzMEonTV Kindly make it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`module` object is already available in context. So replace

```
{% for lesson in lessons %}
```

to

```
{% for lesson in module.lesson_set.all %}
```